# 3D libgdx rotation

Tags: android, 3d, rotation, libgdx

I think this question is not a duplicate, or if it is, I couldn't understand how to make this work.

(sorry for my great drawing capabilities...)
[image: Rotation Schema]

I have a ball, radius 0.5 (so, perimeter is 3.1415926).
In each frame, I have it in `oldPosition` and I want to place it in `position`, so, move in the blue arrow direction, represented by the v vector in the drawing. This is easy.

The trick is that I want the ball to be rotated in the target position. The rotation axis should be perpendicular to the direction (green dashed line), and rotation should be performed in relation to the object center (rotation will be 2x the length of the translation).

My libgdx code at the moment looks like:

```
// During object initialization I have a Matrix4 with identify
Matrix4 rotation = new Matrix4();


// Now, this code during render()
Vector3 movement = position.sub(oldPosition);
float length = movement.len();

// drawing this on paper, it seems a correct way to compute orthogonal vector
rotation.rotateRad(new Vector3(-movement.z, 0f, movement.x), 2*length);

iSphere.transform = rotation.cpy().trn(position);
```

So, basically, I start with the identify Matrix4. In each frame I apply a rotation to it, apply that rotation in the sphere, and translate it.

This seems to work at first (?), but after a lot of rotations, ball starts rotating in the wrong direction.

I tried an implementation with Quaternions but did not have luck as well. It should be something simple that I am forgetting.

Comment: It's a bit vague what you exactly want to achieve. Perhaps add an image/drawing to make it more clear.

Comment: As much as i understood you want to move the ball and rotate it arround his own axis while moving. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Added a (wonderful) drawing, and rephrased the text. Hope it helps. @Springrbua has it right.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly how to do it with the libgdx 3D API, as i don't know much about it. But i guess you should store a `Vector3` direction, the direction in which you are moving. Then you can rotate the ball arround the crossprodukt of your direction and the Y-axis. I guess @Xoppa can tell you whats the best way to do that in libgdx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Springrbua said you could take the cross product to get the axis to rotate around. For example (untested code):

```
public void update(float delta) {
    velocity.add(tmpV.set(acceleration).scl(delta));
    position.add(tmpV.set(velocity).scl(delta));
    final float speed = velocity.len();
    final float angle = speed*delta*MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;
    Vector3 axis = tmpV.set(velocity).scl(-1f/speed).crs(Vector3.Y);
    tmpQ.set(axis, angle);
    rotation.mulLeft(tmpQ);
    transform.set(position, rotation);
}
```

Here's the full source of a working example: https://gist.github.com/xoppa/3b841fb52f46e8cdec24

Comment: I tried and it seems that sometimes the ball is rolling in the opposite direction, almost like my own implementation. Also, just in order to understand fully, that scale is equivalent to a normalize `nor()`, right?

Comment: That was caused by the order of the matrix multiplication. I've updated the answer to use separated components, which you probably should use anyway as explained here: http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=17878&p=75338#p75338

Comment: As a sideway comment, if the quaternion multiplication were done with the `mul` method, the behavior would be the same as my original code. So, it might be relevant to stress que `mulLeft` usage.