# Ball rolling on an incline plane java libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to program my own physics (no box2d answers please) and I want a ball to roll on any incline plane it touches. I have a good amount of experience in physics but for some reason I can't seem where to find how to do this in programming anywhere. Any help on how to tackle this problem is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think geometrically!

First you need to find out if and which plane the ball touches. Create a vector from the balls position that points straight *down*. Find the nearest plane this vector intersects. This can be done with vector math, e.g. the basics you find in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection

You now know the plane and you can calculate the distance between ball and plane intersection point. If the distance is <= balls radius, it touches. From there, calculate the planes slope and modify the balls movement vector accordingly (to your physics model).

Answer (score 1):

From the very limited information you've given it looks like a duplicate of [3D libgdx rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262490/3d-libgdx-rotation/28324665), for which you can find an example as well at https://gist.github.com/xoppa/3b841fb52f46e8cdec24